# Import one module of a package from a different one (in the same package)

Tags: python, package

Assume I have the following structure of a package:

```
parent/
  package/
    __init__.py
    utils/
      __init__.py
      foo.py
    apps/
      __init__.py
      bar.py
```

Now, I want to import the module `foo` from the module `bar`. What is the correct way to do it? I will welcome comments on the structure of my project :)

So far I only found answers where everything lives in the same directory... I tried something like:

```
from ..utils import foo
```

but I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bar.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..utils import foo
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py I'm still checking...

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's better to set some environ variable or extend PYTHONPATH (it must be done in main script)